# How would I go about having an email sent to a user that has created a profile?

Tags: html, reactjs

Essentially once the user creates the profile they'll get a message saying the profile is created and would have an email sent confirming the created profile. This is an example of what I have so far.

```
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: input.first_name.toLowerCase(),
        last_name: input.last_name.toLowerCase(),
        phone_number: input.phone_number.toLowerCase(),
        org: input.org.toLowerCase(), 
        email: input.email.toLowerCase(),
        password: input.password,
        role: input.role
    })
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(json =>{ //When the responce is a promise you .then the .json() to get the promise value
        if (json){
            dispatch(addUserSuccess());
            toastr.success(
                'Success!',
                'User has been added'
                'E-mail confirmation sent'
            );
        } 
        else{
            dispatch(addUserFailure());
            toastr.error(
                'Failure',
                'Unable to add new user'
            )
        };
    });

};
```

};

Comment: Server-side, you can start by looking at nodemailer, you can use transports like gmail and SendGrid. You added client-side code here, so I'm not sure if you're asking how to send email client-side, which you don't want to be doing as you would be exposing the information needed to send emails on your behalf within your client code.